# cannot load such file -- tml (LoadError) in Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing `rails 4.2.6` application where used below gems

```
gem 'globalize', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'tml-rails', '~> 5.4.1'
gem 'tml', '5.4.5'
```

But i got below error when try to run project

```
   "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - https://tools.translationexchange.com/tml/stable/tml.min.js"


TypeError: jade_mixins.language is not a function
```

What is wrong here? any one have a idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you run the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

In Gemfile edit this:

```
gem 'tml', '~>5.4.5'
```

Run:

```
bundle install
```

Hopefully it will work. Thank you

Comment: Thanks but i solved it. can you please check question which i updated.